# Kubernetes liveness probe: webhook notification on failure

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm running a Kubernetes cluster on Google cloud. My cluster has a deployment that exposing the health-check interface (over HTTP). In my deployment `yaml` file, I configured:

```
livenessProbe:
  # an http probe
  httpGet:
    path: /hc
    port: 80
    scheme: HTTP
  initialDelaySeconds: 30
  timeoutSeconds: 60
  periodSeconds: 90
```

If my health check endpoint return anything but 200, the pod will be killed and restarted.

Currently, after pod restart, it just counts it on the "restart" counter but not notify anyone. I want to notify the sysadmin that this event has happened. I thought to notify with a webhook.

Is this possible? If not, what is my other notification alternative?

Answer (score 1):

The somewhat convoluted standard answer to this is Kubernetes -> kube-state-metrics -> Prometheus -> alertmanager -> webhook. This might sound like a lot for a simple task, but Prometheus and its related tools are used much more broadly for metrics and alerting. If you wanted a more narrow answer, you could check out Brigade perhaps? But probably just use kube-prometheus (which is Prom with a bunch of related components all setup for you).

Comment: Hey, the answer isn't clear to me. Where I can find the `webhook` you specified (`Kubernetes -> kube-state-metrics -> Prometheus -> alertmanager -> webhook`)? what is `Brigade`? Do I need 3rd party component to archive this goal?

Comment: Yes, Prometheus is a third party tool (though also under the CNCF umbrella so it’s a sibling project). Alertmanager is the thing that would actually trigger the webhook, it is the component of Prometheus that deals with sending alerts.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [`preStop hook`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/) to your pod spec. The hook can either run a script or make an HTTP call before the pod shuts down. You can configure the hook to call an API which triggers a notification.

Comment: Interesting. I can see here two problems: 1) `preStop` not says the reason for the stop and I want to differentiate normal stop from health-check probe failure. 2) The hook is actually run the script on the container. If the health-check probe failed because of connectivity - the hook will never send.

Comment: If the container is completely unresponsive, you are right, it won't send anything. The alternative is a mix of logging and monitoring that sends alerts like pager duty or datadog based off your préférer logging/monitoring agents

Comment: I'm using Stackdrive logging with sink to logs to the notification. But, the message won't arrive the Google's logging server if no connectivity (and I had this case 2 weeks ago)

Comment: It depends what you are looking for. You might find the logs you want from the kubelet or from the node. If a container is failing, thetr are multiple places to collect logs. Using stackdriver, look at kubelet or docker logs