# what's the simplest way of monitoring whether a pod is running in k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring

My scenario looks like this:

- I have a k8s cluster running
- in this k8s cluster i have a statefullset defined, within the statefullset I have a pod running, say it's `podName-0`

What I would like to achieve is, whenever the `podName-0` is not in running status, send a email to someone and someone is going to fix this.

I tried using Prometheus to make it but it looks a bit heavy (e.g. `ClusterRole`/`ClusterRoleBinding`/etc)

Is there any simple way to achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is opinion based and cannot be answered unambiguously. I will try to outline a few ways to solve the problem for you, but I cannot say which will be "easier". Everything has its pros and cons. But to the point. First look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58708580/kubernetes-liveness-probe-webhook-notification-on-failure):

[Coderanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/78722/coderanger) writes:

> The somewhat convoluted standard answer to this is Kubernetes -> kube-state-metrics -> Prometheus -> alertmanager -> webhook. This might sound like a lot for a simple task, but Prometheus and its related tools are used much more broadly for metrics and alerting. If you wanted a more narrow answer, you could check out Brigade perhaps? But probably just use kube-prometheus (which is Prom with a bunch of related components all setup for you).

This is great explanation why you can use Prometheus and what additional advantages are associated with it.

Going further. [Patrick W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9231144/patrick-w) mentioned:

> You can add a [`preStop hook`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/) to your pod spec. The hook can either run a script or make an HTTP call before the pod shuts down. You can configure the hook to call an API which triggers a notification.

A similar solution was proposed in the second answer to this question. If you decide to use preStop hook read also [this doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-termination).

Another way is to use an external tool such as [Atomist](https://atomist.com/). On the blog you can find this [article](https://blog.atomist.com/kubernetes-health-alerts/) about Kubernetes Health Alerts.

See also:

- [Kubernetes and Containers Best Practices - Health Probes](https://www.magalix.com/blog/kubernetes-and-containers-best-practices-health-probes)
- [Configure Liveness, Readiness and Startup Probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/)
- [Container hooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#container-hooks)
- [Another blog article about the same :)](https://theithollow.com/2020/05/18/kubernetes-liveness-and-readiness-probes/)

Answer (score 0):

To detect your podName-0 changing from running to terminating unexpectedly, you can use a [prestop hook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#container-hooks) to make a callout. If you need more than 30s (by default), you can set terminationGracePeriodSeconds to a longer period.

```
...
spec:
  ...
  template:
  ...
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: busybox
        ...
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command: ["<callout>"]
      ...
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
```

This is probably the simplest possible. Since Prometheus is mentioned, you can checkout [Alert Manager rules](https://awesome-prometheus-alerts.grep.to/rules.html) available for comprehensive check and trigger. This method does not require any special RBAC apart from the standard Prometheus installation requirement.

Comment: I don't think this approach will work if the node the pod on fails, or if the node suddenly runs out of memory and the underlying Linux kernel kills your pod.